# Some multicharacter emojis doesn't render correctly

Tags: unicode, emoji

I am trying to create an emoji with Ubuntu 22.04. Almost all emojis are rendering correctly in both my Qt app and terminal except some multicharacter emojis like ❤️‍ ❤️‍️‍️

[image]
[image]